# Error xcodebuild NSFileHandle couldn't write. Exception: *** -[_NSStdIOFileHandle writeData:]: Broken pipe while generate Apollo GraphQL API

Tags: xcode, graphql, xcodebuild, cicd, apollo-ios

Helpppp ! I just want to get my pipeline run successfully T.T Anyone can help me here~

**Situation:** I am integrating Apollo client in my iOS project and following the instruction provided by official Apollo - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation (using SPM way to setup). It works all fine for me in Xcode manual compile and testing. However, when I am using the command to run the unit test, I got stuck while generating Apollo GraphQL API. Below is the error I have received while running
`xcodebuild test -scheme ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} -project ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -destination "${XCODE_APPLICATION_PLATFORM}" -enableCodeCoverage YES| xcpretty -s`

**Error:** `xcodebuild[10347:2192409] NSFileHandle couldn't write. Exception: *** -[_NSStdIOFileHandle writeData:]: Broken pipe`

**Note:** This error occurs while I am running unit test through command line in Gitlab pipeline. Using Xcode 13.2.1.

[image]

Comment: hi @janice, do you have any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I found this article online: https://peterthomashorn.info/blog/broken-pipe-in-gitlab-with-xcpretty/

It suggests setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable in gitlab CI to `en_US.UTF-8`. I believe this is setting the character encoding to UTF-8 so that xcpretty doesn't choke on the bytes being piped into it.